# Error en formulario de Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Tengo un error en los input de un formulario,cuando coloco `th:field` y corro el servidor me da el siguiente error.

**ERROR**

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/registrar-ticket.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/registrar-ticket.html]")
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "registrar-ticket" - line 33, col 44)
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
... 48 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "registrar-ticket" - line 33, col 44)
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117)
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918)
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:256)
at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:169)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:104)
at org.attoparser.HtmlVoidElement.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlVoidElement.java:92)
at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:297)
at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:402)
at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:159)
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710)
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'ticket' available as request attribute
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:153)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174)
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
... 63 more

**Controlador

```
import com.edu.ucentral.modelo.ticket;
import com.edu.ucentral.repository.Ticketrepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
public class Ticketcontroller {

    @Autowired
    Ticketrepository ticketR;
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "redirect:/tickets";
    }
    @GetMapping("/new")
    public String nuevo(){
        return "registrar-ticket";
    }


    @PostMapping("/ticket")
    public void registrar(@ModelAttribute ticket tick){
        ticketR.save(tick);

    }
    @GetMapping("/tickets")
    public String ticketList(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("ticket",ticketR.findAll());
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/ticket/{id}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        ticketR.deleteById(id);
        return "redirect:/tickets";
    }
}
```

**Formulario**

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>CRUD Ticket</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" th:href="@{/img/4406665.png}" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img th:src="@{img/4406665.png}" alt="" width="50" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-text-top" >
            Registrar ticket
          </a>
          <a th:href="@{/}">
            <i class="Large material-icons" style="font-size: 50px; color: white;">arrow_back</i>
        </a>
        </div>
        
      </nav>
      <section class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="card shadow col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4   p-4"> 
        <div class="mb-4 d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-1">
                <form id="contacto" action="#" th:action="@{/ticket}" th:object="${ticket}" method="post" >

                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <label for="tipo_solicitud"><i class="bi bi-envelope-fill"></i> Tipo de solicitud</label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{tipo_solicitud}" name="tipo_solicitud"  class="form-control"  id="tipo_solicitud"  required>
                        <div class="correo text-danger"></div>
                        
                    </div> 
                    <div class="mb-4 d-flex justify-content-between"> 
                        <div>
                            <label for="fecha_de_apertura"> <i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i> Fecha_de_apertura</label>
                            <input type="date"  class="form-control" name="fecha_de_apertura" id="fecha_de_apertura"  required>
                            <div class="fecha_de_apertura text-danger "></div>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <label for="fecha_de_cierre"> <i class="bi bi-person-bounding-box"></i> Fecha_de_cierre</label>
                            <input type="date"  class="form-control" name="fecha_de_cierre" id="fecha_de_cierre"  required>
                            <div class="fecha_de_cierre text-danger"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <label for="nombre_solicitud"><i class="bi bi-envelope-fill"></i> Nombre de solicitud</label>
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="nombre_solicitud" id="nombre_solicitud"  required>
                        <div class="nombre_solicitud text-danger"></div>
                        
                    </div> 

                    
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <label for="detalle"> <i class="bi bi-chat-right-dots-fill" required></i> Detalle</label>
                        <textarea name="detalle"  id="detalle" class="form-control" ></textarea>
                        <div class="detalle text-danger"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <label for="estado_solicitud"> <i class="bi bi-chat-right-dots-fill" ></i> Estado solicitud</label>
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="nombre_solicitud" id="estado_solicitud" readonly >
                        <div class="estado_solicitud text-danger"></div>
                    </div> 

                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <button id ="botton" class="col-12 btn btn-primary d-flex justify-content-between ">
                            <span >Enviar </span><i id="icono" class="bi bi-cursor-fill "></i>
                        </button>
                    </div> 
                              
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

En el método `nuevo()` pásale a la vista un ticket vacío:

```
@GetMapping("/new")
public String nuevo(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("ticket", new ticket()); 
    return "registrar-ticket";
}
```